Annotation, summary or abstract
Every scientific article must have a brief description at the beginning which is called summary or abstract. Can we call it annotation?

To get more useful answers, please edit to explain more about why you would want to do this. There are many things we could do—we could call it "a paragraph"—but it's not clear why we would use a word that's less accurate or useful when we have special ones for this situation.

Short answer - no.
Just looking the meanings of the words up in a dictionary will show you that the words have different meanings. The brief description at the beginnings can, indeed be called a summary or abstract.
An annotation is a piece of text inserted into a diagram, map, graph or similar to add information about or highlight some feature. It could also be used to describe a footnote or end note. You can add your own annotation to papers and books by writing them in the page margins or between the lines of print. Again, extra information.
If you do a quick internet search for "annotation", you will get definitions and under "images" there are numerous examples.

Thanks! I have actually done but my university teacher has a different opinion. Thanks again!
